# How to find the ram rom usage (.bss .text .rodata .data) of an object file *.o?

Tags: c++, c, windows, python-3.x

I am trying to write a script to find out the RAM-ROM usage (RAM = bss + data,
ROM = rodata + text) of and object file. I tried with a GreenHills compiler tool that generates a report, but for some cases it doesn't work. Is there a way to find the memory sections to calculate the usage ?

Comment: You tagged 3 distinct languages, which one you want to ask about?

Comment: When it does not work? Can you add it? And why python, windows and c++?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The normal way would be to check the linker output "map file". How to do that and where to find it depends on compiler.

Comment: As for your problem, the true usage can't be found out until you link your application (for example by examining the map file as mentioned).

Comment: You need to link first

Comment: I recommend having the GreenHills compiler generate a *map* file.  Next, write a SNOBOL program to search the map file for your information.

Answer (score 0):

@B. Vlad  You should count alignments when allocations in memory are done too. As suggested above, the only reliable way is to use linker output, as it will provide "memory" map of the objects with addresses they are loaded to( before loaded in memory though).